# How to fix airflow error: print_context() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ds'

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dag as below:
ingest_excel.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time
from builtins import range
from datetime import timedelta
from pprint import pprint

import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
#from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'rxie',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='ingest_excel',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
)

def print_context(**kwargs):
    pprint("DAG info below:")
    pprint(kwargs)
    return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'


t11_extract_excel_to_csv = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t1_extract_excel_to_csv',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)


t12_upload_csv_to_hdfs_parquet = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t12_upload_csv_to_hdfs_parquet',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)


t13_register_parquet_to_impala = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t13_register_parquet_to_impala',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)

t21_text_to_parquet = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t21_text_to_parquet',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)

t22_register_parquet_to_impala = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t22_register_parquet_to_impala',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)

t31_verify_completion = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t31_verify_completion',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)

t32_send_notification = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t32_send_notification',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(),
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)

t11_extract_excel_to_csv >> t12_upload_csv_to_hdfs_parquet
t12_upload_csv_to_hdfs_parquet >> t13_register_parquet_to_impala

t21_text_to_parquet >> t22_register_parquet_to_impala


t13_register_parquet_to_impala >> t31_verify_completion
t22_register_parquet_to_impala >> t31_verify_completion

t31_verify_completion >> t32_send_notification


#if __name__ == "__main__":
#    dag.cli()
```

In DAG GUI it prompts:

> Broken DAG: [/root/airflow/dags/ingest_excel.py] `python_callable`
>   param must be callable

This is my first dag in Airflow, and I am pretty new to Airflow, it would be greatly appreciated if anyone can shed me some light and sort it out for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on your issue: your process is broken because you're not passing the function `print_context` to the `PythonOperator`, you're passing the *result* of calling `print_context`:

```
[...]

t32_send_notification = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t32_send_notification',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context(), # <-- This is the issue.
    op_kwargs=None,
    dag=dag,
)

[...]
```

Your function is returning the string `'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'` which is, in turn, being provided to the `PythonOperator` in the `python_callable` keyword argument. Airflow is essentially attempting to do the following:

```
your_return = 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'
your_return()
```

...and you're receiving the error you see. The other contributor is correct in stating that you should change your `PythonOperator.python_callable` keyword argument to simply `print_context`

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration, joeb

Answer (score 3):

The following option needs to be passed to PythonOperator in the newer versions of airflow:

```
provide_context=True
```

Otherwise the ds parameter is not passed to your function. This was a recent change to Airflow that I ran into.

Complete Example:

```
def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    pprint(kwargs)
    print(ds)
    return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_the_context',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. adding `provide_context=True` works @JackDavidson

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you're code doesn't work. It *should* work, but a work around is given below.

```
def print_context(**kwargs):
ds = kwargs['ds']
```

also the python_callable should be passed like this

```
python_callable=print_context,
```

Comment: Thank you very much. removing the () resolved the issue.